# Asynchronous request handling with ES6

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to send multiple requests asynchronously, but only one is getting finished - all remaining have `xmlhttp.status == 0`, and `xmlhttp.readyState == 1` for the whole time, four times each.

What's wrong?

I have two files, `Api.js` and `Ajax.js`. Api is sending requests using Ajax:

`Api.js`:

```
import Ajax from './Ajax';

class Api {

    returnData (success, failure) {
        var params = {
            methodId: this.ids.returnData,
            requestBody: {}
        };
        this.sendRequest(params, success, failure);
    };

    sendRequest (data, success, failure) {
        Ajax.execute(function (response) {
            success(response); // simplified
        });
    };

}

export default new Api();
```

`Ajax.js`:

```
class Ajax {

    createXmlHttp () {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            this.xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            this.xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    };

    onreadystatechange (action, data) {
        this.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
                if (this.xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                    action(this.xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
            }
        }.bind(this);
    };

    execute (action, url, data) {
        this.createXmlHttp();
        this.onreadystatechange(action, data);
        this.xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
        this.xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        this.xmlhttp.send(data);
    };

};

export default new Ajax();
```

Comment: `0` isn't just for incomplete requests, it also can be an error code... and the code you wrote has no error handling.

Answer (score 4):

You only ever create one instance of your Ajax object.

Every time you call `Ajax.execute`, you overwrite `this.xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();`

You need a new instance of `Ajax` for each request.

> ```
> export default new Ajax();
> ```

Don't create the instance there:

```
export default Ajax;
```

… create it when you need a new object.

```
sendRequest (data, success, failure) {
    new Ajax.execute(function (response) {
```